# Cant open file with associated app

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, cmd

I created an app. I have some files which I need to open with this app. So I made the association with the commands below:

```
assoc .bengi=BengiFile

ftype BengiFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Bengi\CreateAS.exe" "%1" %*
```

After these, I can see that my file's icon has changed according to my app's icon. But when I double-click on it, the app is not opened. Can you tell what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

to get the path of the file, I added the folowing code into main function in Python script:

```
if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    print sys.argv[1]
```

When I try to run it manually from command prompt, there is no problem: The app is run, and I can get the file path correctly. However, When I double click on a .bengi file, I get error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you code you application with such argument passing in mind (i.e. in the `main` method)?

Comment: No. I dont know anything about that. Do I need to add some code to my app?

Comment: How are you making your py scripts into an exe?  Py2exe?  When you run your exe as you have it configured above what does print sys.argv[1] print?

Comment: I use pyinstaller. print sys.argv[1] does not print at all. I just get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code in your application startup (`main` method) to parse the command line arguments and open the file.

I suggest reading about this topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx).

This would normally look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // parse args, do something with them (like open the file specified)
}
```